# Install packages in CentOS from DVD without connection to internet

Tags: linux, centos, yum, centos-6

I have a CentOS 6.4 system with no connection to internet. I have the [installer DVD](http://ftp.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/CentOS/6.4/isos/x86_64/CentOS-6.4-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso) though. How can I install a package, say gcc, using this DVD alone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us assume the ISO is already burnt into a DVD, or the ISO is present as a file on your file system. First, we need to mount it. The preferred mount point to mount it is `/media/CentOS`, because `yum` is configured to look for repositories from this location by default while installing packages from DVD. The steps below describe how to mount the ISO (whether present as a file or burnt into DVD) and install packages from the ISO.

1. If you have the ISO burnt into a DVD, insert the DVD into the CentOS system. If the ISO is not burnt into a DVD, but present as a separate file on the file system, then skip the next two steps and go directly to step 4 in this list.
2. Check if the DVD has been mounted automatically. To do this execute the following command:

   ```
   mount | grep CentOS
   ```

   If this command returns an output, it means the DVD has been mounted. For example, the following example output shows that the DVD has been mounted to `/media/CentOS_6.4_Final` automatically.

   ```
   /dev/sr0 on /media/CentOS_6.4_Final type iso9660 (ro,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks,uid=500,gid=500,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500)
   ```
3. If the CD has been mounted automatically, then ignore this step. Otherwise, mount it manually.

   ```
   mkdir /media/CentOS
   mount -t iso9660 /dev/sr0 /media/CentOS
   ```
4. If the ISO is present on the file system, mount it to `/media/CentOS` using the `mount` command with `-o loop` option.

   ```
   mount -o loop CentOS-6.4-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso /media/CentOS/
   ```
5. Execute: `cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo` and read the information provided as comments in this file. See the repo name within square brackets. It is `c6-media` by default. Also, see the locations specified for `baseurl` property. These URLs point to local directories `/media/CentOS`, `/media/cdrom` and `/media/cdrecorder/` by default.
6. If the DVD is mounted to a mount point specified in the `baseurl` property, then ignore this step. Otherwise, create a symbolic link at a location specified in the `baseurl` property with the mount point as its target. An example follows.

   ```
   ln -s /media/CentOS_6.4_Final /media/CentOS
   ```
7. In the shell, execute the `yum` command while disabling all repos except the repo specified in `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo`:

   ```
   yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=c6-media install gcc
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Installing CentOS packages from CentOS DVD iso on VirtualBox**

Insert CentOS DVD image in VM:

```
Devices->Optical drives->CentOS-8.5.2111-x86_64-dvd1.iso
```

DVD will be visible at following location:

```
/run/media/user/CentOS-8-5-2111-x86_64-dvd/
```

Login as root:

```
su root
```

Create Directory /media/CentOS

```
mkdir /media/CentOS
```

Run following commands to mount package repositories under /media/CentOS:

```
$> ln -s /run/media/user/CentOS-8-5-2111-x86_64-dvd/BaseOS/ /media/CentOS
$> ln -s /run/media/user/CentOS-8-5-2111-x86_64-dvd/AppStream /media/CentOS

$> ls /media/CentOS/  
AppStream BaseOS
```

Check status of repositories using command:

```
$> yum repolist all
```

Enable our media repos:

```
$> yum config-manager --enable=media-appstream
$> yum config-manager --enable=media-baseos
```

Disable all other repos:

```
$> yum config-manager --disable=[repoid]
```

Run following command and you will see all available packages:

```
$> yum list
```

Install package using command:

```
$> yum install <package-name>
```